# vbscript function to handle all my HTML header code

Tags: html, asp.net, function, vbscript

I'm creating an ASP.net website and I need to use a VBScript to handle my  code using a function so that every time i call that function it writes that code in html.

Something like this:

```
function heading(tite){
   <html>
   <head>
   <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso8859-1">
   <title><%= title %></title>
   </head>
   }
```

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it Asp.Net or Classic ASP (3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% sub heading(titl) %>
<html><head>your html here<% =titl %>
</head>
<% end sub %>
</html>
```